# SQL Server 2008 R2 split one row of results into two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

In simple terms the table (t1) looks like this:

```
id     hours    dollars
-----------------------
abc     4         40
```

I'd like to get results from the table that looks like this:

```
abcHours      4      0
abcDollars    0      40
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try simple query, using operator Union:

```
Select  'abcHours' as  abcHour, hours as Hour, 0 as dollar
Union all
Select  'abcDollars', 0, dollars
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpivot with `cross apply`:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    (concat(id, 'Hours'  ), hours, 0      ), 
    (concat(id, 'Dollars'), 0,     dollars)
) as x(newid, hours, dollars)
```